# How to turn off spell checking WebStorm of css?

Tags: css, webstorm

When using WebStorm project development mode, you need to construct some of the sass or css styles.

However, the spelling checker will prompt a warning url error, but in fact this address because it uses a relative path, there is no wrong.

And error will be thrown to the overall project.

How to turn off this image in css addresses spell check?

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

When clicking alt + enter here after is shown below:
[image]

---

[image]

Comment: I do not see any spell checker in action here -- "Cannot resolve directory" message is definitely not what comes from a spell checker. In any case: if it's possible to suppress, then Alt+Enter while having caret on the error and see what menu it will show you.

Comment: 1) Can you please share such sample file (just extract some code into separate file that would reproduce the issue)? I've tried to replicate it here .. but as soon as I have used `+ $var` construction it just removed all error marks: https://postimg.org/image/ohc7gtxmv/

Comment: 2) Where did you had your caret located **exactly** when you invoked Alt+Enter? On this image I have had it on `123.png` and this is what I see: https://postimg.org/image/vvxeeo3av/ (If you choose "Disable Inspection" it will disable it for all files; or choose "Edit inspection profile settings" and it will take you to that particular inspection (so that you know where to find it); You can also choose "Suppress for xxx" option -- it should add an comment that will tell IDE to ignore such error in that particular place)

Comment: from the screenshot is seems that the url() value can't be parsed. Similar code is correctly parsed for me, no errors reported. What WebStorm version do you use? Can you provoide a file that shows up the issue?

Comment: @LazyOne  Posted a lower side in FIG.take a look.I guess it is not supported by check webstorm js string expression.

Comment: @lena WebStorm 2016.1.1,file screenshot below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solve this problem, use like this:

[image]